# Bring to front with appendChild - can't use text field (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I want to use appendChild to bring div elements to front in a simple web application. I listen for click or mousedown (I have tried both) and then reappend whatever has been clicked to the main div container. Like this:

**JavaScript**

```
document.querySelector("#container").addEventListener("click", function(event) {

    for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i += 1) {

        if (this.children[i].contains(event.target)) {

            this.appendChild(this.children[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

However, when I try this in Firefox the text fields in the div elements becomes unselectable. You can't put the marker in the text fields. It works in Chrome but not in Firefox. What could be the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Currently, because of this problem, I am using a different method with z index. But I would prefer to use appendChild as it has other advantages.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First time I've seen someone do `i += 1` instead of `i++`.

Comment: Could you create a simple demo of the problem?

Comment: Yes, but not tonight =) I'll do it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

This is a direct consequence of the `appendChild` which temporarily removes from DOM the child that contains the clicked Element (including when clicking to select text or to put caret / focus in a text input field), to re-append it at the end of the `div` children (but the text selection is now gone).

A simple workaround would be to leave the clicked child in DOM, but move its below siblings up until the clicked one is the last child.

```js
document.querySelector("#container").addEventListener("click", function(event) {

    var found,
        children = this.children;

    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i += 1) {
        if (children[i].contains(event.target)) {
            //this.appendChild(children[i]); // Do not detach from DOM.
            found = children[i]; // Leave it in place.
        } else if (found) {
            this.insertBefore(children[i], found); // Swap with found sibling.
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/x53eh5b3/1/